# Trumbowyg: How to put text using Jquery .html() or .text()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, editor, trumbowyg

How to put retrieved text into Trumbowyg Textarea.
I want to edit saved content using Trumbowyg.
I have getting some text from database using Jquery Ajax.
I am trying to put text using .html() and .text() function, but not working.
I am trying to find solution from internet till now not get it.

HTML:

```
<textarea name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("data-id");  
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: "formName=edit_sales_lead&id=" + id,
                success: function(res){
                    if(res!=""){
                            res=JSON.parse(res);
                            console.log(res[1]);  //test description
                            $("input[name='name']").val(res[0]);   
                            $("textarea[name='description']").html(res[1]);
                    }else{
                        console.log(res);
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Do you know where to find the trumbowyg api?  I would imagine they'd have a method for this

Comment: Please visit https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/

Comment: Please visit https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation/#manage-content

Comment: I will checkThankyou

Comment: Working thanks @Taplar

Comment: Apis are your friend, :)

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML = '<p>Your html content</p>';
```

or as suggested by @Taplar in comments:

```
$('#editor').trumbowyg('html', "<p>Your content here</p>");
```

would be another way of loading html content.